# How does shape size impact container fill rate?

Tags: probability

Imagine that you are placing randomly-sized shapes (lines in 1d, rectangles in 2d, etc) is a cuboid-shaped container. I am interested in how increasing the average shape size (and size variance) impacts the effectiveness of how well the cuboid is filled.

I did a lot of research on this mainly on Wikipedia (Knapsack problem and bin packing) but I didn't find what I was looking for. I am looking for resources on a specific relationship (or approximation) for how shape size $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ impact the % of cuboid filled. Intuitively, if you are filling a cuboid with very small cubes, you will get a near perfect fill rate, but if you are filling with large cubes (i.e. almost the same size as the container) then it will be much worse.

The only good resource that I found so far was [here](http://www-personal.umich.edu/%7Edineshk/math_stuff/min_num_rv_threshold.pdf) which explains the 1d case in more detail and he number of cubes you can fit into the container tending to $x/\mu+\mu^2/\sigma^2$.

Comment: Your question is unclear, because "placing" could mean many things.  Do you have some algorithm to locate these shapes within the container or are they placed randomly according to some distribution?  What about the distribution of their sizes and shapes (aspect ratios)? Are all shape edges parallel to the container sides or can they be rotated?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on my question :) Some more information on those points:

Comment: - For the "placing algorithm", I am assuming they are being placed optimally (with no time complexity constraints). I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213394/what-algorithm-can-be-used-for-packing-rectangles-of-different-sizes-into-the-sm which outlines some of the most efficient algorithms. I think I am happy to use greedy algorithm for my use case.

Comment: - The distribution of their average size could be anything theoretically but for now I am assuming they are normally distributed with $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$.
- For simplicity, I am assuming all of the shapes are rectangles/cuboids and must have straight edges parallel to the container sides.

Comment: There are some fundamental issues here.  The first is that there is no true optimal algorithm: they are all approximations. Any answer must depend on the algorithm.  Even different greedy algorithms can lead to different answers, so you have to be specific.  The answers are even more sensitive to the distributions of shapes and sizes. The problems become apparent when you actually try to carry this out: regardless of how small the cuboids are and even with optimal (sequential) placement, there is going to be non-vanishing amounts of empty space.